# strchrnul on visual studio c++?

Tags: c++

I recently received an old source code from a port scanner program that worked in the old Visual Studio, but this source does not work in Visual Studio 2019.

```
p = strchrnul(h, ',');
```

The strchrnul function is not inside the string.h header file.
Can any of you help replace this function ? I have no knowledge of text in cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `strchnul()` implementation easily enough:

```
char * strchnul(const char * s, int c)
{
   while(*s)
   {
      if (c == *s) break;
      s++;
   }
   return const_cast<char *>(s);
}
```

Comment: bro i get this on return s;   cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Comment: Fixed (filler for minimum-comment-length here)

Comment: In C++ there should be two versions of this function: `char* strchnul(char*, int)` and `const char* strchnul(const char*, int)`. All of the non-const-correct C string functions got this transformation.

Comment: also I believe it is meant to be `if (*s == 0 || *s == c)` hence the `nul` in the name

Comment: @Orwellophile the checking for `*s == 0` is handled in the `while(*s)` line.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner nit picking here, but if (c == 0) you might be in trouble ;)

Comment: @Orwellophile AFAICT if (c == 0) the function will return a pointer to the string’s NUL-terminator byte.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I think you'll find the returned result might not match what is expected if 0 is passed in as `c`.  I think I came up with that suggestion after reading some existing implementations. YMMV.

Comment: @Orwellophile I tested just now with `const char * s = "foobar"; printf("s=%p nul=%p\n", s, strchrnul(s, 0));` and got the output `s=0x10e1aef96 nul=0x10e1aef9c`, which is the behavior I would expect based on the function's description at https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchrnul

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I checked that man page, and the freebsd one, and both fail to specify how a null would be handled on a strchnul, but I think it is reasonable to say your assumption that it would return a pointer to the end of a string is reasonable.  It is also supported by this chromium implementation: https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-newlib/+/refs/heads/main/newlib/libc/string/strchrnul.c
I run some tests https://onlinegdb.com/t2oi2P9dd and my suggested change produces results not in line with other implementations. -- my apologies, you were right.

Comment: From the linked page:  "The terminating null byte is considered part of the string, so that if c is specified as 0, these functions return a pointer to the terminator."